# Why is I-20 issued by the Department of Justice, not the Department of Homeland Security or the Department of Education?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, international-travel, paperwork, study

I-20 is a required form that describes an educational program and determines legal status for F-1 foreign students in the United States.

Here's a sample I-20: http://www.unh.edu/oiss/sites/www.unh.edu.oiss/files/general/i-20_2.jpg

Comment: That form dates to 1988!

Answer (score 4):

It *is* issued by DHS nowadays. The forms you're seeing haven't been updated since DHS was created; these matters used to be handled by the Immigration and Naturalization Service in the Justice Department (where most federal law enforcement was located), but in 2003 INS was split into various pieces and all were transferred to DHS (which was created that same year).

Comment: An updated form is coming out soon (see http://studyinthestates.dhs.gov/sites/default/files/Redesigned%20Form%20I-20%20Fact%20Sheet.pdf (PDF)), which will say "Department of Homeland Security" at the top.  Note that the revision date at the bottom of the current form is in 1988!